# Looping a table, selecting data from other tables and return combined data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PGSQL. I have multiple schema in database, in one schema I have a table containing names of schema in different rows. I have same set of tables in every schema with different data. I want to loop through the table(Table A for example) that contains name of all schema and select the data from table B from every schema and then return the combined result.

```
Table A
id schema_name
1   schema_A
2   schema_B
3   schema_C

schema_A.table_B
//some data in table

schemaB.table_B
// some data in table
```

I am trying to create a query that will output the combine result of table_B from all schema.

Comment: I don't thik this is possible in plain SQL because the FROM clause is static: you need to build the query dynamically either in application code or in PL/pgSQL database code.

Answer (score 0):

It would look something horrible like:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(sAtB.Value1, sBtB.Value1, sBtC.Value1) as value1_from_some_schema,
  COALESCE(sAtB.Value2, sBtB.Value2, sBtC.Value2) as value2_from_some_schema
  ...
FROM
  schemaA.tableA tA
  LEFT JOIN schemaA.tableB sAtB ON tA.schema_name = 'schema A' AND tA.id = sAtB.id
  LEFT JOIN schemaB.tableB sBtB ON tA.schema_name = 'schema B' AND tA.id = sBtB.id
  LEFT JOIN schemaC.tableB sCtB ON tA.schema_name = 'schema C' AND tA.id = sCtB.id
  ...
```

Comment: I want to do it using a for/while loop since I am not sure how many entries of schema would be present in table_A

Comment: Why would this not cope with that?